# How to implement an S-estimator for an MM-estimator in python

Tags: python, r, regression, linear-regression, robust

I'm trying to implement an MM-estimator in python. I have a working implementation of an M-estimator [statsmodels.RLM](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_1.html)  - which is implemented as an iteratively re-weighted least squares algorithm. I am struggling to implement the initial S-estimator, my understanding is that an S-estimator is an M-estimator of scale however none of the R packages ([mass.rlm](https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/rlm.R), [robustbase.lmrob](https://github.com/cran/robustbase/blob/master/src/lmrob.c), [robust.lmRob](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/master/R/lmRob.q)) I've found seem to implement this as an iteratively re-weighted least squares problem. Therefore, my question is what algorithm should I use to implement an S-estimator, and how should I implement this in python ideally only using [numpy](https://numpy.org) and [scipy](https://scipy.org).

Here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Install robustbase
# from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
# utils = importr("utils")
# utils.install_packages("robustbase")

import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
robustbase = importr("robustbase")
ctrl = robustbase.lmrob_control()

rng = np.random.default_rng()
nsample = 50
x1 = np.linspace(0, 20, nsample)
x1[-10:] += 5
X = np.column_stack((np.ones_like(x1), x1, (x1 - 5) ** 2))
# X = sm.add_constant(X)
sig = 0.5  # smaller error variance makes OLS<->RLM contrast bigger
beta = [5, 0.5, -0.0]
y_true2 = np.dot(X, beta)
y2 = y_true2 + sig * 1.0 * np.random.normal(size=nsample)
y2[(a:=np.arange(0, 50, 4))] -= rng.random(a.size)*50
y2[-10:] -= 20

x2r = ro.r.matrix(X, nrow=nsample, ncol=3)
y2r = ro.FloatVector(y2)


def mad(x, axis=None, centre=0):
    return np.median(np.abs(x - centre), axis=axis) / 0.6745


def huber_t_weights(z, t=1.547):
    absz = np.abs(z)
    test = absz <= t
    absz[test] = 1
    return test + (1 - test) * t / absz


def m_estimator(x, y, n):
    wls = sm.WLS(y, x, weights=np.ones_like(y)).fit()
    params = wls.params
    resid = y - x @ params
    scale =  mad(resid)
    for _ in range(n):
        weights = huber_t_weights(resid / scale)
        wls = sm.WLS(y, x, weights=weights).fit()
        params = wls.params
        resid = y - x @ params
        scale = mad(resid)
    return params
    
    
m_me = m_estimator(X, y2, 50)
    

mm_robustbase = robustbase.lmrob_fit(x2r, y2r, control=ctrl)[0] # MM estimator
m_sm = sm.RLM(y2, X).fit().params # M estimator
o_sm = sm.OLS(y2, X).fit().params # OLS estimator

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x1, y2, "o", label="data")
ax.plot(x1, y_true2, "b-", label="True")
ax.plot(x1, X@mm_robustbase, "g-", label="MM-estimator (robustbase))")
ax.plot(x1, X@m_sm, "k-", label="M-estimator (statsmodels))")
ax.plot(x1, X@m_me, "y-", label="M-estimator (me)")
ax.plot(x1, X@o_sm, "r-", label="OLS (statsmodels)")
ax.legend()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I think you may have better luck getting an answer if you address your question to the  [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) site. Be sure to read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: @itprorh66 well [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it says to avoid asking the same question on multiple sites, and that  'implementation question that can be answered without reference to data, it is better suited for Stack Overflow'

Comment: asking for a recommendation as to which algorithm is best for your use case is outside the scope of this site, since it generally leads to opinion based answers.

Comment: @itprorh66 I'm interested in any algorithm that implements an S-estimator